# Need to create persistent share between Linux and Windows Server 2012 r2, options?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

So we have a need for this type of share, and I'm not sure how best to do this.

Basically files will be created on a Centos 6.x box, and that directory (and the files that are created) need to be accessible from a Windows Server 2012r2 box at all times.  I know how to create an NFS share on the Linux box, and installed NFS client on the 2012r2 box and know how to mount that share, however I don't see any way to keep this persistent when I either log off the 2012r2 box, or when it needs to be rebooted.

Is there a "good" way to do this?  I found a workaround, but started thinking this can't be a rare need (to have a persistent share between Linux/Windows) so is there a better way that doesn't involve having to purchase additional software?

Comment: Have a look at samba.

Comment: Isn't there any automount solution on windows server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to install [Samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/what_is_samba.html) on the CentOS 6 system, expose your mount point as a network share, and create a persistent drive letter on the Windows box with `net use`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into [subst](https://superuser.com/questions/217561/why-is-a-subst-drive-usable-from-a-command-prompt-but-not-windows-7-explorer) as it pertains to mapping a drive letter to a remote share. There are more specifics about using it on boot at the link above. Be aware that only the user executing the `subst` command would be able to access that share however so you may need to take that into account when utilizing the mount point.